# Does RichEditBox text need to be encoded/decoded when saving/retrieving? (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my UWP app I have a RichEditBox. I use richEditBox.Document.GetText() to get the contents of the editor, but it doesn't take any encoding parameters. So how do I know what encoding is being used, and does the contents of the RichEditBox need to be encoded at all? I ask because I will soon be localizing my app and I'm afraid that someone in a different region will end up seeing gibberish when they save/retrieve data. I'm just not sure that the results will be consistent in all cases.

Also note that after I get the rtf text from the editor I simply save the string to a SQLite database, then I use richEditBox.Document.SetText() to load the data from the db back into the editor. Seems too simple, and that's why I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s that simple.

Both the Windows Runtime [Platform.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/platform-string-class) and the .Net [string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string) class it projects into are Unicode (UTF-16) and so don’t need separate encodings for different languages.

You only need to convert if you’re aiming for an external target with different requirements. If you’re just round tripping from .Net/WinRT and back then you can leave everything in the default UTF-16 encoding.

See the [Globalization and Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/globalizing-portal) docs for other issues in the area that you will want to design for.

Comment: Thanks. I feel more secure with what I've coded now.